# Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found error when run composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to run composer in ssh but it gives this output when run:

> Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found in ...composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 23

I working add "Socialite" class to laravel; So I must be run this code;

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

But, it's output is this:

> Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found in ...composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 23

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? And what version of Socialite are you requiring?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I using Laravel 6.0 and I need to version 2.0 of Socialite.